# Calculating pay dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date

We use a bi-monthly payroll where employees get paid on the 15th and last days of the month.

If those days fall on a Saturday, Sunday or holiday, then we get paid on the last day before then that isn't a Saturday, Sunday or holiday.

For example, take this week, April 15th is a Friday but its defined as a holiday so people should be paid on Thursday April 14.

I managed to get a partial query working where I can exclude weekends and holidays but I can use some help figuring out what DATE people should be paid on. My output should only include pay days. I would like to produce a years output Jan-dec for the current year.

I was thinking perhaps last_day() for the last pay day of the month once holidays and weekends were excluded?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_dates(i_from_date IN DATE, i_end_date IN DATE, i_min_delta IN NUMBER, i_max_delta IN NUMBER, i_num_rows IN NUMBER) 
RETURN VARCHAR2 
SQL_MACRO 
IS 
BEGIN 
RETURN q'{
SELECT start_date, end_date
   FROM ( 
        SELECT pivot_date AS start_date, pivot_date + NUMTODSINTERVAL( i_min_delta + (i_max_delta-i_min_delta) * DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(), 'hour') AS end_date 
        FROM (
            SELECT pivot_date + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() AS pivot_date            
            FROM ( 
                SELECT rownum AS rn, pivot_date AS pivot_date FROM ( 
                    SELECT TRUNC(i_from_date)+level-1 AS pivot_date FROM DUAL 
                    CONNECT BY TRUNC(i_from_date)+level-1<=TRUNC(i_end_date) 
                ) 
            ) 
            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= i_num_rows AND PRIOR rn = rn AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL 
        )
    ) 
}' ; 
END;
/

create table holidays(
          holiday_date DATE not null,
          holiday_name VARCHAR2(20),
          constraint holidays_pk primary key (holiday_date),
          constraint is_midnight check ( holiday_date = trunc ( holiday_date ) )
        );

INSERT into holidays (HOLIDAY_DATE,HOLIDAY_NAME)
        WITH dts as (
          select to_date('15-APR-2022 00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'Passover 2022' from dual union all
          select to_date('31-DEC-2022 00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'New Year Eve 2022' from dual
        )
        SELECT * from dts;

SELECT
        c.dt,
       to_char(c.dt, 'DY') as dow
FROM generate_dates(
TIMESTAMP '2022-01-01 00:00:00',
TIMESTAMP '2022-04-30 00:00:00',
 1, 'DAY') c
where 
to_char(c.dt, 'DY') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN') 
AND NOT EXISTS (
             SELECT 1
             FROM   holidays h
             WHERE  c.dt = h.holiday_date
           );
```

Comment: Are you sure that `generate_dates` macro is the one you are using as you are calling it with an entirely different set of arguments to the arguments defined in the signature and the macro return the columns `start_date` and `end_date` whereas your query uses the `dt` column.

Comment: Also, I'm also not sure that your `generate_dates` function will work consistently as you add initially add `DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE()` and then add an amount of hours and if the first random amount is close to 1 then you can fail to generate a value for a day and instead generate two days for the next day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate the dates using the query:

```sql
WITH pay_dates (dt) AS (
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YY'), LEVEL) - INTERVAL '1' DAY
  FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12
UNION ALL
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YY'), LEVEL - 1) + INTERVAL '14' DAY
  FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12
),
skip_weekends (dt) AS (
  SELECT CASE dt - TRUNC(dt, 'IW')
         WHEN 6 THEN dt - 2 -- Sunday
         WHEN 5 THEN dt - 1 -- Saturday
         ELSE        dt     -- Weekday
         END
  FROM   pay_dates
),
skip_holidays (dt, holiday_date) AS (
  SELECT w.dt, h.holiday_date
  FROM   skip_weekends w
         LEFT OUTER JOIN holidays h
         ON (w.dt = h.holiday_date)
UNION ALL
  SELECT CASE s.dt - TRUNC(s.dt, 'IW')
         WHEN 0
         THEN s.dt - 3 -- Monday
         ELSE s.dt - 1 -- Other weekday
         END,
         h.holiday_date
  FROM   skip_holidays s
         LEFT OUTER JOIN holidays h
         ON ( CASE s.dt - TRUNC(s.dt, 'IW')
              WHEN 0
              THEN s.dt - 3
              ELSE s.dt - 1
              END = h.holiday_date )
  WHERE  s.holiday_date IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT dt
FROM   skip_holidays
WHERE  holiday_date IS NULL
ORDER BY dt;
```

Which for the holidays:

```
CREATE TABLE holidays (holiday_date) AS
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YY') + INTERVAL '12' DAY FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YY') + INTERVAL '13' DAY FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YY') + INTERVAL '14' DAY FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YY') + INTERVAL '45' DAY FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| DT |
| --- |
| 2022-01-12 (WED) |
| 2022-01-31 (MON) |
| 2022-02-14 (MON) |
| 2022-02-28 (MON) |
| 2022-03-15 (TUE) |
| 2022-03-31 (THU) |
| 2022-04-15 (FRI) |
| 2022-04-29 (FRI) |
| 2022-05-13 (FRI) |
| 2022-05-31 (TUE) |
| 2022-06-15 (WED) |
| 2022-06-30 (THU) |
| 2022-07-15 (FRI) |
| 2022-07-29 (FRI) |
| 2022-08-15 (MON) |
| 2022-08-31 (WED) |
| 2022-09-15 (THU) |
| 2022-09-30 (FRI) |
| 2022-10-14 (FRI) |
| 2022-10-31 (MON) |
| 2022-11-15 (TUE) |
| 2022-11-30 (WED) |
| 2022-12-15 (THU) |
| 2022-12-30 (FRI) |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EeWauM1l)

Comment: MTO thanks for responding and your expertise. Could your solution be implemented with my generate_date function and my logic to skip weekends and holidays. It's just that our company prefers to use common functions and methodologies across all our applications

Comment: @Pugzly My solution directly generates the pay dates and then skips backwards over the relevant weekends and holidays so it does not generate extra unnecessary rows. Your solution appears to generate rows for every day and then tries to filter out weekends and holidays which is an entirely different approach to the problem (and is much less efficient); while I'm sure you could implement it as you do, I would not want to as I'd prefer to use the more efficient approach (and an approach that does not rely on language-specific functions).

Answer (score 0):

I think the basic idea I would follow is getting all the dates without weekends and holidays, then finding the maximum day of each month and the maximum day of each month that is <= the 15th.

Get all dates without weekends and holidays:

```
WITH noholidays AS
(
SELECT dt
FROM 
 generate_dates(
  TIMESTAMP '2022-01-01 00:00:00',
  TIMESTAMP '2022-04-30 00:00:00',
  1, 'DAY') c
WHERE to_char(dt, 'DY') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
 AND dt NOT IN (SELECT holiday_date FROM holidays)
)
```

Then, from there, get the maximum date for each month `union`ed with the maximum date that is <= the 15th of each month.

```
 SELECT max(dt) payday
 FROM noholidays
 GROUP BY to_char(dt, 'YYYY-MM')
UNION ALL
 SELECT max(dt)
 FROM noholidays
 WHERE to_number(to_char(dt, 'DD')) <= 15
 GROUP BY to_char(dt, 'YYYY-MM')
ORDER BY payday
```

There's a [working example in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uQmW3lHm), although I used a CTE to generate all the dates in the current year ([borrowed from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59970982/sql-function-to-select-first-day-of-current-year-and-everyday-after)) since your `generate_dates` function didn't compile for me (but you can just use `generate_dates`).

I think your final solution would look something like:

```
WITH 
noholidays AS (
 SELECT dt
 FROM generate_dates(
  TIMESTAMP '2022-01-01 00:00:00',
  TIMESTAMP '2022-04-30 00:00:00',
  1, 'DAY')
 WHERE to_char(dt, 'DY') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
  AND dt NOT IN (SELECT holiday_date FROM holidays)
)
SELECT max(dt) payday
FROM noholidays
GROUP BY to_char(dt, 'YYYY-MM')
UNION ALL
SELECT max(dt)
FROM noholidays
WHERE to_number(to_char(dt, 'DD')) <= 15
GROUP BY to_char(dt, 'YYYY-MM')
ORDER BY payday
```

Comment: The generate_dates function is defined at the top. It was called gen_dates but I renamed it. I would prefer to use commonly used written functions that are accessed in our applications. I will try your solution. Thanks for your time and expertise

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I missed that you did define your function so I could have used that. I will reword my answer.